# one liner in bash (using perl or awk) to change extension of multiple files?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, awk

What's the easiest way in the bash shell to rename a bunch of files? To rename each `*.ext` file in the current directory to `*.otherext`? I'm open to solutions that use perl or awk, doesn't have to be pure bash. Any ideas?

To be clear it would mean:

```
mv a.ext a.otherext
mv b.ext b.otherext
...
etc. for all *.ext
```

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/changing-extension-of-large-number-of.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. There's a `rename` program written in Perl:

```
rename 's/\.ext\z/.otherext/' *.ext
```

But there's also another (incompatible) `rename` program around, for which you'd have to do this:

```
rename .ext .otherext *.ext
```

There's also a program called `mmv`:

```
mmv '*.ext' '#1.otherext'
```

Using plain bash:

```
for i in *.ext; do mv -- "$i" "${i%.ext}.otherext"; done
```

Using plain perl:

```
perl -we 'for my $old (glob "*.ext") { (my $new = $old) =~ s/\.ext\z/.otherext/; rename $old, $new or warn "$old -> $new: $!\n"; }'
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! out of curiosity is there an equivalent one liner in Python to your Perl or is that not possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know python.

Comment: +1 for the plain-Bash version. Incidentally, instead of using `--`, another option is to use `./*.ext` instead of `*.ext` to select the files to iterate over.

Comment: @user248237 it is so that a file that starts with `-` is not considered as an option by `mv`

Comment: A slightly simpler expression for the target filename in the `mv` command would be `${i/%ext/otherext}` (although not POSIX-compliant).

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for what a Python version might look like, I thought I would add it for posterity.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from glob import glob
from os import rename

for f in glob("*.ext"):
  rename(f, f[:-3] + "otherext")
```

The one line version (not as nice looking):

```
python -c "import glob,os;[os.rename(f, f[:-3] + \"otherext\") for f in glob.glob(\"*.ext\")]"
```

Comment: thanks, but I meant it as a one liner from shell... I know how to write it as a full script but was hoping to do a quick one liner. Maybe Python is not suited for this?

Comment: @user248237 Added the one line version.

Answer (score 0):

A python one-liner:

```
python -c "import shutil, glob; [shutil.move(i,i.replace('.txt','.ext')) for i in glob.glob('*.txt')]"
```

Take advantage of ' and " instead of escape characters and the replace function